# Счетчик на javascript

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. Решил в админке сделать текстовое поле с счетчиком символов (то есть что-то вводишь, а тебе снизу показывается сколько символов ты ввел). При помощи *jquery* вытягиваю количество символов в поле, но не знаю как сделать, чтоб цифра кол-ва символов, увеличивалась при наборе текста.

Answer (score 3):

Повесь обработчик на событие `onkeyup` своего контрола.

C html:

```
<textarea id="memo"></textarea>
<div id="counter"></div>
```

на jQuery это выглядит так:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#memo').keyup(function(){
        $('#counter').text( $('#memo').val().length );
    });
});
```

Comment: значение можно через val взять:

    $('#memo').val().length

Comment: И обычно (мне, правда, кажется, что я не совсем догоняю, зачем) пишут примерно так:

    (function($){ /* ... */ })(jQuery);

*т.е. я догоняю, просто кажется, что тут явно что-то кроме красоты етсь)*

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Именно то что нужно.
Действительно помог!

Comment: @Sh4dow, все просто. `$` в качестве ссылки на свой синглтон использует не только jQuery, а и другие библиотеки. А, с помощью

    (function($){ /* ... */ })(jQuery);

`$` экранируется внутри отдельной области видимости. И возможный конфликт `jQuery != $` сводится на нет.

Если все записать классическими конструкциями, то получится более наглядно:

    function foo($){
        /* ... */
    }
    foo(jQuery);

@aachurin, да, верно. Спасибо.

Comment: И:

    jQuery(function(){/* ... */});

это тоже что и:

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){/* ... */});

но, имхо, более лаконичный вариант записи.

Comment: @KiTE, спасибо, логично)

Answer (score 0):

Это же просто.
На `$.keyup` - подсчитывай количество символов в тексте с помощью length
http://api.jquery.com/length/